# Booting Ubuntu from USB while running Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, usb, gparted

I've looked everywhere and all I can find is how to do this from Windows, however I'm trying to resize a partition to install Windows to. I'm attempting to boot from a USB while currently running Ubuntu 16.04. Grub will not recognize the startup disk, that I had made with the Ubuntu ISO written on it, on start up.

The end goal is to resize my partition dev/sda1 ext4, that happens to have 99% of my free space. I cannot umount it because it contains the OS that I'm running and I cannot resize it because it is in use because I'm logged on.
This is why I've been trying to boot from the USB to resize this partition, I'm new to linux but I'm convinced that booting from the USB will allow me to unmount the partition that I'm trying to resize.

Comment: Please describe how you created your USB boot drive: Which version of Ubuntu (the same 16.04 as is installed)? Which tool to install from the iso file to the USB drive? Can you activate a temporary boot menu via a *hotkey* (can vary, different hotkey in different computer)? An alternative is to *chainload* from the internal grub boot to the USB drive. See this link, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Booting_the_Computer_from_USB

Comment: Is your bios set to boot from usb prior to hard drive?

Comment: I used the command.

[code] sudo dd if=/path/to/iso.iso of dev/sdb bs=4M status=progress[\code]

Thank you I'll try this link and let you know how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is an update for anyone who may be experiencing a problem similar to this. From my research it seemed to be somewhat unique. I'm not going to include codes, just the names of what I ran to fix as the problem was more general and the solution less professional.

Recap:
I recently wiped my hard drive with a powerful magnet, my hands were full and I accidentally let it get too close and that was that. So naturally I bought a new hard drive and installed the only ISO that I had on hand — Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I was not thinking too far ahead during the installation, and being a Linux noob, I clicked okay to install to my main hard drive — which happened to be completely empty. (This is what is different to most problems I found researching, most had Windows already installed). So the OS was installed onto the main hard drive and I had little problems until I tried to get Windows on a seperate partition.

I was unable to resize the partition because it was currently running the operating system. For some odd reason the GRUB would not recognize the USB that I had written with the 'dd' command to write a new one because I read the startup disk program could be buggy. Still nothing was recognized.

I then attempted to resize the partition while running, using fdisk, which is a stressful task but I did so starting at the same sector and the second ending at the end of the original. Yet this did not work, so the partition never sized.

Next, I tried to uninstall GRUB using purge and reinstall — this is where I messed up — however, this is what led me to the solution miraculously. The machine purged the grub but would not reinstall- giving an error that prompted ' yes-force install not supported, try using a command with '--allow'. I tried and could not get this to work.

By this time I was running an operating system with a disk that could not boot (because of the GRUB purge), I couldn't shut down using the GUI and I knew that it would not reboot if I did, mind you the BIOS was inaccessible since I installed originally the BIOS code for my laptop would take me straight to GRUB, and now that there was no GRUB it allowed be to
enter BIOS — problem solved.

I changed the boot priority, booted straight the the USB, still no grub so no TRY Ubuntu option but I started an installation where I was able to resize my partition Install Ubuntu onto the second partition, which reinstalled GRUB and now I can pick between the old and new Ubuntu next is to delete the newer installation and reinstall Windows.

Thanks for all the help guys and I hope this helps anyone through the hell I've gone through over the past two weeks into finals week. LOL.

Comment: PS. Warning:


 After purging the GRUB I was unable to access any media, USB or external drives to make a backup...That is why I got frustrated and just turned it off and noticed I could enter BIOS.

A backup and wiping clean making a partition on startup and transferring files back after would have been easier. I didn't have the supplies or time to go buy a external drive.

Comment: **UPDATE:  DO NOT DELETE THE NEW PARTITION IF YOU TAKE THIS PATH.

I deleted the new partition without repairing grub thinking that the recent install had replaced the old GRUB without this file you cannot boot, not even from USB or DVD startups.

I had to go through GRUB Rescue to fix this which was a whole new beast. I'm repair GRUB a little research will show plenty of commands to do this.

Comment: If any experts have a different way to solve this problem please feel free to share, however I tried most of these suggestions and the problem persisted. I researched for weeks and could not find an answer. PLEASE SHARE.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your live disk is working correctly?

If you're able to boot to Ubuntu on your HDD then it sounds like the issue resides with your USB.

https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

This might be of some help.

Just something to check is, does it show up in the BIOS as a bootable disk? It could be that Grub doesn't realize it's there but your BIOS recognizes it as a viable option.

I've had issues with thumb drive live sticks, for whatever reason they don't seem to be as stable as a DVD running the OS. If you're able to create a Live DVD I would try that as well.

Comment: I'm new to the GRUB GUI, so everytime I hold shift and F2 it sends me to GRUB rather than the BIOS. I was wondering if getting into the BIOS was different when running Ubuntu.

Comment: Perhaps you need to set the boot flag on your USB drive:
`$ sudo parted /dev/sdb set 1 boot on`

Comment: Who made your motherboard? Grub is a bootloader, but it loads after your BIOS loads, try F11 or F12, might be Delete too, just depends on your mobo.